# ¿Como crear observables de los eventos click() para toda fila en una tabla de Angular Material y responder a todos ellos?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, rxjs

> Pude hacerlo con un button de HTML también con un button de Angular
> Material Pero en una tabla de Angular Material solo consigo hacerlo en
> la primer fila Utilice primero  fromEvent creando observables que  emiten clicks event al no obTener el resultado
> deseado lo intente luego con Renderer2 tdo indica que @ViewChild solo responde a la primer fila trate entonces  con @ViewChildren() que creo seria la forma tampoco logre hacerlo dentro de una tabla de angular material

```js
import { Renderer2,AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, OnDestroy, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { defer, fromEvent, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime, map, tap, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

// modal de una tabla
export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
  {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
  {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
  {position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},
  {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
  {position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},
  {position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},
  {position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
];

/**
 * @title Basic use of `<table mat-table>`
 */

@Component({
  selector: 'app-material',
  templateUrl: './material.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./material.component.scss']
})
export class MaterialComponent implements AfterViewInit , OnInit, OnDestroy{
  buttonsClik!:() => void;
  documentClick!: () => void;
  // funciona con un boton comun se usa { static: true }
 @ViewChild('testBtn', { static: true }) testBtn!: ElementRef<HTMLButtonElement>;

 event$ = defer(() => fromEvent(this.testBtn.nativeElement, 'click')).pipe(
   map(() => new Date().toString()),
   tap(console.log)
 )
 //funciona para un button externo de Angular Material #pdfExterno a la tabla se usa { read: ElementRef }
 @ViewChild('pdfExterno',{ read: ElementRef }) pdfExterno!: ElementRef<HTMLButtonElement>;
// logro capturar solo los eventos de primer fila de la tabla usando distintas estrategias
 @ViewChild('docx',{ read: ElementRef }) docx!: ElementRef<HTMLButtonElement>;

 pdfExterno$=defer(() => fromEvent(this.pdfExterno.nativeElement, 'click')).pipe(
   map(() => new Date().toString()),
   tap(console.log)
  )
  @ViewChild('pdf',{ read: ElementRef }) pdf!: ElementRef<HTMLButtonElement>;
 @ViewChild('mostrar',{ read: ElementRef }) mostrar!: ElementRef<HTMLButtonElement>;

 displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol','descargaPdfDoc'];
 dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
// otra forma intento con Renderer2 intento capturar no solo a los eventos click() de la primer fila
 constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) { }
 ngOnDestroy(): void {
 this.buttonsClik();
 this.documentClick();
 }

 ngOnInit(): void {
   this.event$.subscribe();
 }

 ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.pdfExterno$.subscribe()
   this.render();
   console.log(this.pdf);
   console.log(this.docx);
   console.log(this.mostrar);
    /* Modicficando el codigo intente usar merge solo escucha 1 fila
  
   <div>
        <button  id="pdf"   #pdf (click)="(pdf.id) ;descargarPDF(row)" >PDF</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button   id="docx" #docx (click)="(docx.id);descargarDocx(row)" >DOCX </button>
      </div>
    </div>
*/
   merge(
fromEvent(this.pdf.nativeElement, 'click'),
fromEvent(this.docx.nativeElement, 'click'),

).subscribe((event: Event | null)=> {
  console.log('desde Merge',event?.target);
});

  /* tampoco resulto solo 1 fila creando a un observable que emite click event
   docx$!: Observable<any>;
   this.docx$=fromEvent(this.docx.nativeElement, 'click')
.pipe(

  map(()=>new Date().toString()),
  tap(console.log)
  )
  this.docx$.subscribe(e=>console.log('docx',e))
  */
 }
 render(){
  this.documentClick = this.renderer.
  listen('document', 'click', (event:MouseEvent) =>{

    console.log('Desde render docx',event)
   } )

 this.buttonsClik= this.renderer.
  listen(this.docx.nativeElement, 'click', (event:MouseEvent) =>{

    console.log('Desde render docx',event)
   } )


  this.renderer.listen(this.pdf.nativeElement, 'click', (event) => {
    console.log('Desde render pdf',event)
  })
  this.renderer.listen(this.mostrar.nativeElement, 'click', (event) => {
    console.log('Desde Render mostrar',event)
  })
}
  onDocumentClick(e: any): boolean | void {
    throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
  }
descargarPDF(row:any){
  console.log('pdf',row)
}

descargarDocx(row:any){
  console.log('docx',row)

  }

  onRowClicked(row:any): void{
    console.log('mat-row',row)
  }

  descargarPDFFueraDeMatTable(){
    console.log('funciona')
  }

}
```

```html
<h1>Fuera de la Tabla sin problemas</h1>
<section>
  <div>
    <button #testBtn>Click me</button>
  </div>
  <div>

</div>
</section>
<button mat-raised-button
 (click)="descargarPDFFueraDeMatTable()"
 #pdfExterno>PDF</button>
<h1>Dentro de la tabla solo puede vincular a un Observable para la 1 fila</h1>
<div class="container text-center">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" #mytable class="mat-elevation-z8">


    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Symbol Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="descargaPdfDoc">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Descarga</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="u-text-align-center" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
        <div class="row">
          <div>
            <button mat-raised-button (click)="descargarPDF(row)" #pdf>PDF</button>
          </div>
          <div>
            <button mat-raised-button (click)="descargarDocx(row)" #docx>DOCX </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </ng-container>
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" #mostrar (click)="onRowClicked(row);$event.stopPropagation()">
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
mat-raised-button {
  width: 10px;
 }
```

Comment: ¿Qué finalidad tiene escuchar todos los eventos click? No entiendo para que podrías usarlo

Comment: Modifique la pregunta quizás no se entendía de acuerdo al texto la finalidad de la pregunta gracias

Comment: Perdón nestan, pero sigo sin entender, que finalidad tiene crear observables en cada row. ¿Cuál es el objetivo? Veo lleno de `console.log` No estoy seguro y quizá baste con el listener nativo de HTML5

Comment: El codigo muestra que la finalidad es solo Teorica y lo explico en las características de la pregunta los console.log muestran el resultado de distintas estrategias en todas solo puedo subscribirme a los eventos click de la primer fila de la tabla de angular material

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En stackoverflow en ingles publique esta misma pregunta comparto la respuesta que me dieron la cual responde distinguiendo  a cada fila de la tabla de Angular Material en forma simple y limpia
[respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70560226/8957405)

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

export interface PeriodicElement {
  name     : string;
  position : number;
  weight   : number;
  symbol   : string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  { position: 1,  name: 'Hydrogen',  weight: 1.0079,  symbol: 'H'  },
  { position: 2,  name: 'Helium',    weight: 4.0026,  symbol: 'He' },
  { position: 3,  name: 'Lithium',   weight: 6.941,   symbol: 'Li' },
  { position: 4,  name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122,  symbol: 'Be' },
  { position: 5,  name: 'Boron',     weight: 10.811,  symbol: 'B'  },
  { position: 6,  name: 'Carbon',    weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'  },
  { position: 7,  name: 'Nitrogen',  weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'  },
  { position: 8,  name: 'Oxygen',    weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'  },
  { position: 9,  name: 'Fluorine',  weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'  },
  { position: 10, name: 'Neon',      weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne' },
];

interface RenderJob {
  type: 'pdf' | 'docx';
  data: PeriodicElement
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  private rowClick$  = new Subject<PeriodicElement>();
  private renderJob$ = new Subject<RenderJob>();

  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
  displayedColumns = [ 'position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol', 'descargaPdfDoc'];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.rowClick$.subscribe(
      row => console.log('[row clicked]', row)
    );
    this.renderJob$.subscribe(
      ({ type, data }) => console.log(`[render job received] type: ${type}`, data)
    );
  }

  descargarPDF(row: PeriodicElement) {
    this.renderJob$.next({ type: 'pdf', data: row });
  }

  descargarDocx(row: PeriodicElement) {
    this.renderJob$.next({ type: 'docx', data: row });
  }

  onRowClicked(row: PeriodicElement): void {
    this.rowClick$.next(row);
  }

  descargarPDFFueraDeMatTable() {
    console.log('funciona');
  }

}
```

Responde a cada evento clik dentro de la tabla de angular material

```html
h1>Fuera de la Tabla sin problemas</h1>
<section>
  <div>
    <button #testBtn>Click me</button>
  </div>
  <div></div>
</section>
<button mat-raised-button (click)="descargarPDFFueraDeMatTable()">
  PDF
</button>
<h1>Dentro de la tabla solo puede vincular a un Observable para la 1 fila</h1>
<div class="container text-center">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" #mytable class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>No.</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.position }}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.name }}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Weight</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.weight }}</td>
    </ng-container>
    <!-- Symbol Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Symbol</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.symbol }}</td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="descargaPdfDoc">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Descarga</th>
      <td
        mat-cell
        *matCellDef="let row"
        class="u-text-align-center"
        (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
      >
        <div class="row">
          <div>
            <button id="pdf" (click)="descargarPDF(row)">
              PDF
            </button>
          </div>
          <div>
            <button id="docx" (click)="descargarDocx(row)">
              DOCX
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </ng-container>
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr
      mat-row
      *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"
      #mostrar
      (click)="onRowClicked(row); $event.stopPropagation()"
    ></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```